# Check if value exists in Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is there any way to check for a value in any of the row/column of the dataTable without using [search](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()) ? Search on the data is filtering the displayed rows and I don't want them to be filterer. I just want to check if the value exists or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. Using the `cell().data()` [API call](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data()) you can get/set cell data like this:

Get

```
 var cellData = Table.cell(rowIndex, columnIndex).data();
```

Set

```
Table.cell(rowIndex, columnIndex).data() = cellData;
```

Comment: Interesting.  So the only way to search the data in entirety is to loop through it?